# Can't pass path name created from QFileDialog to QLineEdit in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created a QDialog window with a QLineEdit field and Browse button to pass the path of a folder into a program I am working on, I have problem with it primarily at point of running program, the path has not been generated.

Nonetheless, please see my codes below:

```
def RPA_OCR_module(self):
    # Define the dialog window
    d_width = 500
    d_height = 200
    module_form = QDialog()
    module_form.setGeometry(int((width/2)-(d_width/2)), self.y(), d_width, d_height)
    module_form.setWindowTitle('RPA OCR Module')

    # Define text for text field
    l_col = 20
    element_width = 350
    element_height = 25
    path_field_text = QLabel('Key in the path to working folder', module_form)
    path_field_text.setGeometry(l_col,25, element_width,element_height)
    path_field_text.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 14))
    path_field_text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    # Define the text field
    working_folder_path_field = QLineEdit('Default', module_form)
    working_folder_path_field.move(l_col,50)
    working_folder_path_field.resize(element_width,element_height)
    # Define browse button for directory name
    browse_btn = QPushButton('Browse', module_form)
    browse_btn.setGeometry(l_col+element_width+1,48, 119,element_height)
    browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.openDirNameDialog)
    try:
        if QFileDialog.Accepted:
            working_folder_path_field.setText(fileName)
        else:
            pass
    finally:
        pass

    x = module_form.exec_()

def openDirNameDialog(self):
    # options = QFileDialog.Options()
    # options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    global fileName
    fileName = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory")) # , options=options
    if fileName:
        print(fileName)
        #self.working_folder_path_field.setText(fileName) # This doesn't work, so I commented it out
    else:
        pass
```

If anybody has any idea how to get this done, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Global variables are evil. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `working_folder_path_field` to `self.working_folder_path_field` so you can access it from another function. Then you just have to call `setText()`. Here is a generic template to follow.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton('Browse')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.box = QLineEdit()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.box)

    def open(self):
        name = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory")
        if name:
            self.box.setText(name)
```

Comment: Dammit, works like magic! You are a live saver.
Thanks so much, mate!